# Regarding the designing of ..xsl file in eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt

I am using the .xsl file that define the style and format for my pdf report that is it defines the style and layout for my pdf report , I an using eclipse ,I want is there any plugin in which we can see the outcome of .xsl file in eclipse itself just like the html file we have source tab and design tab in eclipse where while doing coding we can see the design tab to see the design also side by side , please advise for such plugins where we can see the outcome of .xsl file in design mode also

Answer (score 0):

The XSL Tooling is installed as part of the Web Tools Project. With that, you can run the XSL file from within Eclipse as you request -- you can even debug the XSL if you need.

I recommend following Vogellas tutorial at http://www.vogella.com/articles/XSLT/article.html